# Dismissal of dialog box when touch outside

Tags: android, popup, android-alertdialog, dismiss

I tried and also googled on this stuff but not getting answer

i am inflating a view on click now i want to dissmissal of inflated view but its not happening 
here is my source...

```
icon1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)screen.getSystemService(screen.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
               layout =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_popup,null);

               AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Actvity.this);
               builder.setCancelable(true);
               builder.setView(layout);
```

***i dont want to add positive or negative button***

```
 builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

               final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create(); 

               alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon1);
               alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: try to used `Custom Dialog` instead of `Alert Dialog`

Comment: builder.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

Comment: i tried this 1 but not working  @SainathPatwarykarnate

Comment: builder.setCancelable(true); is called two times

Comment: ok removed this and tried again...

Comment: @SimplePlan you can see i am also trying custom dialog but its not happening !!!
can u explain a bit more?

Comment: @user3467110 try as per _Biraj_ answers what's wrong in that? or used `PopWindow`  is the best approach

Comment: thanks it solved my answer ... @Simple Plan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use custom dialog and use this method to reach your requirement `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);`

**Example**

```
public void getCustomOkDialog(Context mContext) {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.ok_dialog);

    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    TextView txtMessage = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
    txtMessage.setText("Your Message");
    dialog.show();

}
```

Comment: Yes use given method just replace the R.layout.ok_dialg with your layout file

Comment: i did but clicking outside is not working...  @Biraj Zalavadia

Comment: Hi I update the answer just remove the theme from constructor and try